# intent starts again after finish

Tags: android, android-intent, exit, activity-finish

I use a button to exit my app,however,when I am exit it and press the recent app button(picture below)
and re-enter my app through the grey screen,instead of starting the app from the main activity,its start from the recent activity and crash because it has bo data..
even when the app is crashed,when I press again on the gray activity its open the second activity again and crash again..

Picture of the grey screen( https://ibb.co/TqPnXJR )

How can I fix it that when the user click on the grey screen it will launch the main activity?

This is my code:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Stop Navigation ");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to stop navigation?");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                exitButtonPressed = true;


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);

                //finishAffinity(); 
                //System.exit(0); 
                //finishAndRemoveTask(); 
                //android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

// I TRIED ALL THE ABOVE BUT ITS ITS NOT WORKING.. 



            }
        });
```

Thank you !!

**EDIT:**

When click on the gray square it activates OnResume..

I noticed that every time I remove my task and enter through my foreground service to the second activity its happening.
I think its about the pending intent.

this is my pending intent code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
i.putExtra("AddressBackground22", mAddress);
i.putExtra("AddressType22", mAddressType);
i.putExtra("AddressLatBackground22", destinationLat);


PendingIntent activityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 25, i, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Action action2 = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_cancel, getString(R.string.remove_location_updates), servicePendingIntent);

NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_launch, getString(R.string.launch_activity), activityPendingIntent);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
            .addAction(action)
            .addAction(action2)
            .setColor(getColor(R.color.foreGroundBackgroundColor))
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Simply call

```
finish();
```

on button click

Comment: yeah you are right but there should be finishAffinity(); not finish();

Comment: Hey @Abhnav Maurya thanks for replying!
If I use only finish(); its showing me the recent apps menu,and instead of the grey screen,I can see the activity running..When I am enter my app through recent apps its just crash..

Comment: @Mr.Goomer Can you send the log? Run the app. reach this dialog. and reopen the app. finishAffinity(); will close all the running activity. The issue might be in other activities. Such as main or your splash.

Comment: This is the log untill onResume start:

https://pastebin.com/Lr2hCAhq

It shouldn't resume but start the application from the first activity..

Thank you

Comment: Remove that intent code. And onResume runs when some activity comes in front and user go back to the app. If app in background (minimized) App starts from onCreate.